# Partial match MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to show all results that contain the word (or words) that a user has searched for. I have some code below that works to an extent, however when an extra word is added to the end of a matched result, it returns no results.

If a user searches for "Fork" it will return all results that matches "Fork", if however they type "Fork Parts", it won't return any results because there are no categories called "Fork Parts". I do, however, want to return results because the word "Fork" was matched.

```
function getCat($string) {
    global $wpdb;

    $cat = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT *
        FROM wpmj8c_term_relationships
        LEFT JOIN wpmj8c_term_taxonomy
        ON (wpmj8c_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wpmj8c_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN wpmj8c_terms on wpmj8c_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wpmj8c_terms.term_id
        WHERE wpmj8c_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'  && wpmj8c_terms.name LIKE '%".$string."%'
        GROUP BY wpmj8c_term_taxonomy.term_id
    ");

    echo $cat;

    foreach ($cat as $search_result) {
        echo '<li><a href="/product-category/'.$search_result->slug.'">'.$search_result->name.'</a></li>';
    }

}

<ul>
    <?php getCat("Fork"); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should show what's inside your database.... Your code would find "Special Fork Parts" or "Special Fork Parts ABC" but *not* "Fork Special Parts"

Comment: I guess I could re-word what I've said. If a user searches for "Fork" it will return all results that matches "Fork", if however they type "Fork Parts", it won't return any results because there are no categories called "Fork Parts". I do, however, want to return results because the "Fork" was matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

() will make the difference.

```
$arr = explode(' ','this test test1');
    $str = '';
    $i = 1;
    $arrCount = count($arr);

    foreach($arr as $v){
        if($arrCount > 1 && $i == 1) { $str.= '('; }
        $str.= 'wpmj8c_terms.name LIKE "%'.$v.'%" ';
          if($arrCount > 1 && $arrCount == $i) { $str.= ')'; } elseif($arrCount > 1 && $arrCount != $i) { $str .= " OR " ;}
        $i++;
    }

$cat = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *
    FROM wpmj8c_term_relationships
    LEFT JOIN wpmj8c_term_taxonomy
    ON (wpmj8c_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wpmj8c_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN wpmj8c_terms on wpmj8c_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wpmj8c_terms.term_id
    WHERE wpmj8c_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'  AND  $str
    GROUP BY wpmj8c_term_taxonomy.term_id");
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Although this answer does answer my question, I have another side question; what would be the best way to go about showing results that closest match the users search term at the top of any results? For example if they search "Accessories", since it's an exact match, have that display first?

Comment: To do that you need to write 2 queries and store the result in separate array variable and merge them. First get result for 'Accessories' (using =), then get related result (using LIKE %%). Now make sure the first result is not repeated in second result (may be you can compare ID and get the unique from second result and merge with the first result).